# How to correctly install ffmpeg on windows XP?

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, ffmpeg

I'm working on C++ project on Windows which involve FFmpeg library.
The problem is that I can't include ffmpeg library to my project. I can't even run any of ffmpeg tutorials or examples. I'm always getting errors like the following:

```
tutorial01.c:22:28: ffmpeg/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
tutorial01.c:23:29: ffmpeg/avformat.h: No such file or directory
```

and lots of errors like:

```
tutorial01.c:33: error: `iFrame' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I found the tutorial with this instructions:

```
//gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lz
//to build (assuming libavformat and libavcodec are correctly installed
//your system).
```

After further searching I found out that I should get a static build library version from here:
http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
Then I installed this library following these instructions:

1. Get the latest build from the arrozcru autobuilds page
2. Unzip the folder into C:/Program Files/ffmpeg
3. Add C:/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin to your system’s PATH environment variable

But I still have compilation errors of the same kind.
So, it seems it was not correct installation.

What should I do to connect ffmpeg library to my project on Windows?

Comment: Can you post exactly what you did when you got those errors? Did you install ffmpeg by downloading the source and then running configure; make; make install? Also are you using mingw/msys, or are you trying to build inside MSVC?

Comment: How I made installation:
1. I downloaded static library - FFmpeg git-6bfb304 32-bit Static (Latest) (2012-04-09) - from here http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
2. I Unzipped the library into C:/Program Files/ffmpeg
3. Added C:/Program Files/ffmpeg/bin to my system’s PATH environment variable
How I'm trying to build my example:
I opened command promt and typed "gcc-3 -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec -lz"

Also I tried to install fmmpeg by compiling the source.. I used this tutorial -http://rmn-explores.blogspot.com/2010/07/ffmpeg-building-on-windows_29.html. But not successfully(

Comment: Have you added the ffmpeg/include, i.e. the directory where avcodec.h is located, to gcc's include directires? Your problem is that gcc can't find the ffmpeg's headers.

Comment: Oh, now i realize I have to add ffmpeg libraries to gcc's include folder. But what type of library (static, dev or compiled source) I need to put there?
I compiled source on Linux then put ffmpeg folders to include folder. I created simple C file which contain only one string: `av_register_all();` and I got error `undefined reference to _av_register_all`

Comment: Is that a compiler error or a linker error? Can you post the entire line containing the error?

Comment: /cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/ASAVCH~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/ccSdnN9S.o:tutorial01.c:(.text+0x292
): undefined reference to `_av_malloc' after gcc-3 -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavformat -lavcodec

Comment: Well it looks like a linker error. Have you added the path where ffmpeg's lib files are to gcc lib directories (that would be LD_LIBRARY_PATH)?

Comment: Then you can mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to summarize the answer, you needed to add ffmpeg's include and lib directories to the directory paths of gcc.